# What is this S-outline with 2-dot eyes icon on Samsung lock screen?

Tags: samsung, lock-screens

Sometimes the touch screen on my Samsung Galaxy A72 stops working and when I reset it via the buttons, this icon that looks like S-outline with 2-dot eyes pops up on the lock screen.

[image]

What is this?

Comment: Its either from some app or a logo for the ISP.  What do you see when you press it ?

Comment: Possible similar issue: [What does this "gear with a ladybug" icon mean on Samsung devices?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/249625/44325)

Answer (score 1):

This icon bothered me for a few days but finally got the answer.

It's the icon for System UI. In my case it came on because the phone was recently restarted. It would stay on screen for a few seconds then disappear.

Go to settings -> notifications -> advanced settings -> notification history, you should be able to find it when you click on system UI.

Hope this helps.

P.S: My phone is a Samsung A03s but should apply across the board to other Samsung phones

This is how it looks on mine:

[image: System UI icon on Samsung lock screen]