# What does this "gear with a ladybug" icon mean on Samsung devices?

Tags: samsung, notification-icons, samsung-galaxy-tab-s8

Samsung Galaxy Tab S8 Ultra, this icon (a gear with a ladybug? The sun holding the letter T?) suddenly appeared on my "swipe to unlock" screen.

[image]

Now the touchscreen is unresponsive and can't enter recovery mode. The only thing I can do is a soft reset.

Comment: Possibly similar issue: [What is this S-outline with 2-dot eyes icon on Samsung lock screen?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/248641/44325)

Answer (score 1):

It's a notification icon for "USB for file transfer". I see it only if the USB cable is plugged in between the phone and the PC, while I restart the phone.

[image: screenshot]

Reference: [The Complete Guide To Icons on Android Devices](https://www.urtech.ca/2020/08/solved-the-complete-guide-to-icons-on-android-devices/)

Answer (score 0):

It can be also a notification for Android System, e.g. after the device restart while finishing a system update.

[image]